# Object types in Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have an app with `user`s in a database, like this:

- `user`

  - `first_name`: string
  - `last_name`: string
  - `height`: integer
  - `eye_color`: ????

The `eye_color` element is confusing me, because I want to have a finite selection (i.e. users can never select "red" for `eye_color`).

Maybe I even want richer content in `eye_color`s, such as:

- `eye_color`

  - `color`: blue
  - `hex`: 000080
  - `description`: "Like the ocean."

That way, in my app, I could render a user's avatar with `user.eye_color.hex`

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firestore does not have an enumeration type.  If there are limits to what values should be in the database, you have to control that on your own.  [Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) will help you validate data coming from mobile clients.